# SQL Server : Any or IN

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm passing in an XML fragment to a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008, which has a varying number of 'Genres' (0 or more) - I'm looking to perform a query whereby I can return an 'artist' row which has all of the provided genres - if ALL of the passed in genres aren't found then I don't want to return anything.

I was using IN, but this would return if any of the passed in genres were found, I require all of them to be matched. I've also tried to use ANY but if I provide no genres (when there should be some) I still get a match.

For example in the below, I'd like to return the 'Artist' with ArtistName 'Some Artist' which has the pop, electronic and top 40 genres. If 'Some Artist' doesn't have one or more of those genres then nothing should be returned.

```
DECLARE @SomeXml XML

SET @SomeXml = 
'<Genres>
   <Genre name="pop"/>
   <Genre name="electronic"/>
   <Genre name="Top 40"/>
</Genres>'

SELECT ArtistName
FROM Artist a

INNER JOIN GenreArtistLink gal
ON gal.ArtistId = a.ArtistId

INNER JOIN Genre g
ON g.GenreId = gal.GenreId

WHERE a.ArtistName = 'Some Artist'
AND g.GenreName IN(SELECT M.c.value('./@name', 'varchar(255)') FROM @SomeXml.nodes('/Categories/Category') M(c))
```

I've used IN above, but as mentioned it returns if just one of the passed in genres matches, when I'd like it to only return a record if 'pop', 'electronic', and 'top 40' are matched.

Also sorry if there are syntax errors I've had to do it off the top of my head.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: These two statements seem at odds: "I require all of them to be matched", "If 'Some Artist' doesn't have one or more of those genres then nothing should be returned." For your example, the first statement implies that you'd need an artist who had all three categories pop, electronic, top 40. The second statement implies that merely having one of those three is sufficient. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always use a `GROUP BY`/`COUNT` to see that all categories are fulfilled;

```
SELECT ArtistName
FROM Artist a
INNER JOIN GenreArtistLink gal
ON gal.ArtistId = a.ArtistId
INNER JOIN Genre g
ON g.GenreId = gal.GenreId
AND g.GenreName IN(SELECT M.c.value('./@name', 'varchar(255)')
                   FROM @SomeXml.nodes('/Genres/Genre') M(c))
GROUP BY artistname
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(M.c.value('./@name', 'varchar(255)')) 
                   FROM @SomeXml.nodes('/Genres/Genre') M(c))
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bdd83/8).

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks very much for the detailed answer and example. Very much appreciated :-)